# Why is MongoDB not rotating the logs using logrotate?

Tags: mongodb, logrotate

MongoDB/logrotate seems to be failing to rotate the logs and I'm not sure why. Here is my configuration:

In the /etc/mongod.conf:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  logRotate: reopen

processManagement:
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongod.pid
```

I have a /etc/logrotate.d/mongodb file:

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
{
        daily
        rotate 30
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        create 640 mongodb mongodb
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 `cat /var/run/mongod.pid 2>/dev/null` >/dev/null 2>&1
        endscript
}
```

I can see that the PID in the file matches the process but I'm unsure why the log did not rotate:

```
root     22938     1  1 Dec15 ?        00:21:21 /usr/bin/mongod --fork --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

```
cat /var/run/mongod.pid
22938
```

Is there an issue with my configuration? Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you expect a new PID on logrotate?

Answer (score 0):

I use `kill -USR1 $(/usr/sbin/pidof mongod)` which is working fine.

```
$ kill -USR1 $(/usr/sbin/pidof mongod)

$ tail /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log | grep SignalHandler
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-14T23:59:01.622+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23377,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Received signal","attr":{"signal":10,"error":"User defined signal 1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-14T23:59:01.622+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23378,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Signal was sent by kill(2)","attr":{"pid":33744,"uid":475}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-12-14T23:59:01.622+01:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23166,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Log rotation initiated"}
```